# How to incorporate 1 or more spaces in the sed command

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a `sed` command which comments out `cd /path/to/file` if not already commented and looks for substring `--port 1234` and comments out the whole line if not already commented.

Example input:

```
cd /path/to/file
somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
somecode somecode
cd /path/to/file
somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode --shutdown
```

Output:

```
#cd /path/to/file
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode somecode
/new/path/to/file
somecode somecode
#cd /path/to/file
#somecode somecode --port 1234 somecode somecode --shutdown
/new/path/to/file --shutdown
```

**Here's the solution which works very well:**

```
sed -E '\@^cd /path/to/file/@s/^/#/;/--port 1234/!b;/^[^#]/!b;s//#&/;p;s#.*(--shutdown).*|.*#/new/path/to/file \1#' file
```

**Problem**:
However in a case where    `cd /path/to/file` would be indented by 4 spaces in first occurence and 7 spaces in another occurence:        `cd /path/to/file`, how would I edit my solution to account for 1 or more spaces? I've been looking all over and I know theres many ways to do it but I can't figure out where to enter that `1 or more` syntax without breaking the entire solution

Comment: Use `\@^[[:blank:]]*cd /path/to/file/@s/....`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GNU `sed`, you can specify one or more spaces using `\s+` pattern as in POSIX ERE flavor an unescaped `+` is a quantifier that is equal to `{1,}`. In a non-GNU `sed`, you might try `[[:space:]]+`, as `\s` might not be supported by all `sed` versions.

So, you might use

```sh
sed -E '\@^[[:space:]]+cd /path/to/file/@s/^/#/;/--port 1234/!b;/^[^#]/!b;s//#&/;p;s#.*(--shutdown).*|.*#/new/path/to/file \1#' file
```

However, it might be a good idea to still stick to the POSIX BRE friendly `*` quantifier in case `cd` appears strictly at the start of a line, and the following should do:

```sh
sed -E '\@^[[:space:]]*cd /path/to/file/@s/^/#/;/--port 1234/!b;/^[^#]/!b;s//#&/;p;s#.*(--shutdown).*|.*#/new/path/to/file \1#' file
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `\@^cd  */path` (two spaces followed by *) or `\@^cd +/path`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That does not look like that, please check the examples in the *Problem* section of the question. There are spaces at the start of the lines.